# How to fetch files from S3 in pairs by matching filenames?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-nifi

I have the following files on my `S3 bucket`.

```
.
|__ bob.jpg
|__ bob.jpg.gz
|__ sam.jpg
|__ sam.jpg.gz
|__ joe.jpg
|__ joe.jpg.gz
```

I have a `FetchS3` processor that fetches files. However, right now it fetches all the files and what I want to do is fetch files in pairs based on the names. For example, in one pass, I need both `bob*` files and then both `sam*` files and finally both `joe*` files.

Since I am feeding each pair of files into my python script down the line, I `cannot allow` for something like this:

`python myscript.py -file1="bob.jpg" -file2="sam.jpg"`

What I am looking for is to fetch the files in the correct pair so that on each pass my python script will be called like these:

`python myscript.py -file1="bob.jpg" -file2="bob.jpg.gz"`

`python myscript.py -file1="sam.jpg" -file2="sam.jpg.gz"`

`python myscript.py -file1="joe.jpg" -file2="joe.jpg.gz"`

I am thinking about using an `UpdateProcessor` to define a `jpg` file and if that exists automatically assume that there must be a `jpg.gz` file as well for the same file name.

Again, this idea is easier said than done and I am not getting really anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [template](https://gist.github.com/alopresto/2f26863afee6cc3109c1a4c5d33c1234) from which you should be able to do what you are looking for. I went on the assumption that the naming strategy was constant (i.e. `joe.jpg` will always translate to `joe.jpg.gz`).

This template uses `ListFile` to read *only* the "source" files (no `.gz`) from the directory, then updates the attributes to have an `image_filename` and `gzip_filename`, and passes them to an `ExecuteStreamCommand` processor which references the attributes as arguments to the command (`echo` in this case).

There may be a more concise way to do this, but I haven't done a ton of work with the `ListFile`/`FetchFile` processors.

[image: Template screenshot]